# what is the javaagent.jar dependency from appD

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, appdynamics

I need to add this to the central repository. But appD does not give its details such as group id, artifact id etc to add in the proper path. What would that be?

Comment: did my answer solved your query ?

Comment: adding it to the organizational central repo is not a problem as I have added many other jars in similar way. However I wanted to know the group id and artifact id only by which I can add it to the repo. Also it would be easier to add to the pom.

Comment: As I explained in my answer, AppD doesn't provide it as a maven dependency, hence there is no corresponding group and artificat id and if you want you need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

AppDynamics doesn't provide it as a Maven dependency and I think it makes sense as well as it  there is no application code which needs to call the java agent jars method.
But If you want to make it as a Maven dependency(Maybe so that in your organisation you have a same version of jar used everywhere and provide an easy way to get the jar, which IMO is a good practice), then you have to download java agent jar and put it in your private/public maven repository.

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475990/maven-dependency-for-self-placed-jars-in-project-level/43476396#43476396) answer on how to place your own jars to Maven.