# Question on Compile Elasticsearch into a JAR like how it was done in the Maven repository

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, gradle, lucene

I have a Maven project where I have utilized a lot of functionalities from Elasticsearch. More specifically, it was imported in this way:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now that I am making some tweaks to Elasticsearch source code in order to get some extra functionality, and I have compiled my code using `./gradlew assemble` and have import the compiled jar from `ES_SOURCE_CODE_FOLDER/core/build/distributions/elasticsearch-5.6.10-SNAPSHOT.jar` in Maven by specifying a `systemPath` and `scope` (for now, I know this not what people would actually do but just to test out my implementation):

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.10</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>/Users/hatsuyukisakura/elasticsearch/core/build/distributions/elasticsearch-5.6.10-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
```

However I realize that after I do this, I was unable to compile my program anymore, as the following import was no longer working:

```
import org.apache.lucene.index.Fields;
import org.apache.lucene.index.TermsEnum;
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.flexible.standard.QueryParserUtil;
```

My question is, did I compile Elasticsearch in an incorrect way? How am I suppose to compile it in the same way as it is compiled in the Maven repository, so that I can still get my imports from `org.apache.lucene` working?

In case if these information are needed:
My changes to Elasticsearch code are very limited, based on a branch off `857bfc2ac43ae3986197aeb2177ab5ff87d9f3b4` which still have the 5.6.10 as version number.
My working environments are:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_212-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.212-b03, mixed mode)

$ mvn --version
[MVNVM] Using maven: 3.5.2
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T00:58:13-07:00)
Maven home: /Users/hatsuyukisakura/.mvnvm/apache-maven-3.5.2
Java version: 1.8.0_212, vendor: AdoptOpenJDK
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.13.6", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"

$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.7
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2018-04-18 09:09:12 UTC
Revision:     b9a962bf70638332300e7f810689cb2febbd4a6c

Groovy:       2.4.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.9 compiled on February 2 2017
JVM:          1.8.0_212 (AdoptOpenJDK 25.212-b03)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark Bramnik 's answer in the follow up section is correct, it is caused by transitive dependencies.

Just remove the system doesn't solve the problem however, I need to do the following:

```
mvn install:install-file \
   -Dfile=/Users/hatsuyukisakura/elasticsearch/core/build/distributions/elasticsearch-5.6.10-SNAPSHOT.jar \
   -DgroupId=org.elasticsearch \
   -DartifactId=elasticsearch \
   -Dversion=5.6.10-X \
   -Dpackaging=jar \
   -DpomFile=/Users/hatsuyukisakura/elasticsearch/core/build/distributions/elasticsearch-5.6.10-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

And then use

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.10-X</version>
        </dependency>
```

Instead

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on the way of compiling ElasticSearch from sources, [Based on this information](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/5.6/CONTRIBUTING.md) it looks like your on track.

However, I can tell, that if after you've come up with a custom distribution, added a dependency in maven and see that `org.apache.lucene.index.Fields` (for instance) is not found, the best way is to open up the artifact itself with Winzip/Winrar or any other program that can open Zip files (because jar is basically a zip), and make sure that the file `org.apache.lucene.index.Fields` indeed exists there.

If its there, then something wrong with your maven definitions, and here many things can go wrong, for example, permissions on generated file if you're on linux or maybe clash with other dependency (you can use `mvn help:effective-pom` to what maven actually decides to pick as a dependency)

If its not there, something went wrong during the Elasticsearch compilation.

Comment: Mark, thanks for providing some debugging info, @Tamaki, please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43475990/maven-dependency-for-self-placed-jars-in-project-level/43476396#43476396 as this might help you

Comment: Here's what's strange. I tried to unzip my jar, `org.apache.lucene.index.Fields` is indeed NOT there. But the thing is, for the original jar file I used from maven (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/5.6.10),  `org.apache.lucene.index.Fields` is also NOT there, but I can import it without any problem!

Comment: Since system scope should be non transitive (please veeify this) it wont pick the transitive dependencies.

Comment: hmmm I tried to remove the system scope and install the jar to local maven repo using `mvn install:install-file` but it is still missing the dependency...

Comment: Install file wont help because it generates the pom without transitive dependencies declaration in your local repository. Hence ghe build system doesn't know which dependencies should be added to the buil process

Comment: Yes you are right - I need to provide pom file manually in the install as what I have done above.